# How Can I Prevent Qt Designer from Applying QPalette to QComboBox - Python

Tags: pyqt5, reset, qt-designer, qcombobox, qpalette

Qt Designer builds a QComboBox that apparently prohibits an editable QComboBox from highlighting when a user double-clicks on the text displayed in the window.  I’d like to have the text highlighted when double clicking in it.

After converting the .ui file to a Python script, I found that Qt Designer created a rather long QPalette that it applied to the QComboBox.  After I commented out all  of the lines of code that builds and applies the palette, the QComboBox behaved as I hoped (highlighted when double-clicked).

I don’t want to have to comment out the lines of code that Qt Designer created every time I make a change to the GUI.  There are two options to fix the issue that I can think of, but I don’t have a solution for either one.

1. Prevent Qt Designer from building the palette via settings within Qt
   Designer.
2. Undo or reset the palette in my Python script.

Is there a solution to my issue?

Here is the palette Qt Designer creates.

```
palette = QtGui.QPalette()
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.PlaceholderText, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.PlaceholderText, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 120, 215))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText, brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.PlaceholderText, brush)
self. myComboBox.setPalette(palette)
```

Comment: You probably set the palette while trying things around. Select the combo, scroll down the property editor panel to the "Palette" property, select it and click the small red arrow button to revert to the default (unset) value.

Comment: @musicamante - That's it!  I overlooked the palette entry in the properties panel and also didn't realize the red arrow button resets the property. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this so that others can quickly see there is a solution.  @musicamante solved my issue with his comment on how to reset the "Palette" property in Qt Designer.